# postgres function returning array

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have the following function (using postgres 9.4)

```
create or replace function toto()  RETURNS text[] AS $$
  DECLARE
    threed text[];
  BEGIN
    select array (select tata from hello)  into threed;
    raise notice 'HERE %',threed;
    return threed;
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

No problem on creation, I ran the function in psql and I get:

```
 select from toto();
 NOTICE:  HERE {055,056,057,058,059}
 --
 (1 row)
```

The notice displays the correct results. What I do not understand is why the results themselves are not displayed ? Where am I wrong ?
 Thanks for any pointer and help

Comment: `select toto()` or `select * from toto()`

Comment: For me **UNNEST** did the trick `SELECT * FROM UNNEST(toto())`

Answer (score 2):

Sorry stupid error
I was calling the function as  select toto()  instead of select * toto();

took me a day to find out :(